# Find all documents which have an attribute in one field OR don't have that attribute in ANY fields

Tags: solr

I'm trying to build a filter query in Solr where I can return the set of users who have failed test x, OR have neither failed, nor passed, nor been invited to test x. The two queries alone look like this:

Set of users who have failed test x. Returns 20 users:

```
fq=failedAssessmentIds:986
```

Set of users who have neither failed, nor passed, nor been invited to test x. Return 1000 users.

```
fq=(-failedTestIds:x AND -passedAssessmentIds:x AND -invitedAssessmentIds:986)
```

Now, when I combine them like this:

```
fq=failedAssessmentIds:x OR (-failedTestIds:x AND -passedAssessmentIds:x AND -invitedAssessmentIds:x)
```

solr only returns the set of 20 users that have failed test x, but doesn't include the 1000 users who have neither failed/passed/invited to test x. How can I get the result to include both sets?

Comment: Can you post an 1 example user document that is result of fq=failedAssessmentIds:x and 1 example document of fq=(-failedTestIds:x AND -passedAssessmentIds:x AND -invitedAssessmentIds:x) . Also please post your field definition and field tupe for failedTestIds, passedAssessmentIds, invitedAssessmentIds and failedAssessmentIds.

Comment: Never mind i think i know situation you may be going through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

fq=failedAssessmentIds:x OR (***:* AND** -failedTestIds:x AND -passedAssessmentIds:x AND -invitedAssessmentIds:x)

The reason is "Not" query purpose is to remove results from matches, it's function is not to find results. I know it is confusing. So when you did not have the first part of the query , when Solr sees just the not query , it automatically does MatchAllDocsQuery and then removes docs that do not match the "not" query. But once you add the first part (failedAssessmentIds:x) it finds those documents and attempts to remove documents that match "not" criteria.